# Security Vulnerabilities if we upgrade newtonsoft.json from 6.0.4 to 9.0.1

Tags: json, security, json.net

would like to know if there would be any security vulnerabilities if we upgraded JSON.net(also known as Newtonsoft.json) from 6.0.4 t0 9.0.1 as I couldn't find any specific details about it in Release notes.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are any security vulnerabilities with this library. It is purely for JSON serialization and it depends completely on the context where you use it. Given that it is .NET managed code there should also be no risk of memory leaks unless something really weirdly has been done there, which I don't believe.

Comment: thanks dustinmoris for your response. and even I would not think of any security vulnerabilities especially because we are just using JsonConvert from the library and wanted to make sure that i'm not missing anything here.

Comment: See the following question for known security issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650272/security-vulnerabilities-if-we-upgrade-newtonsoft-json-from-6-0-4-to-9-0-1